# C++: index out of range

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, range, abort

Here comes the function that I have problem with:

```
ivec sort_index( vec list, int length ) {  //UNSORTED VECTOR OF INPUT VALUEAS

 ivec index;
 index = zeros_i(N);
 float temp = 0;
 int temp2 = 0;

 for ( int j = 0 ; j<N ; j++){
      index[j]=j; // VALUES IN INCREASING ORDER
 }

 int i = 1;
 while ( i < length ){
       for (int k = i; list[k - 1] > list[k]; k--){
            temp = list[k - 1];  //BUBBLE SORT
            list[k - 1] = list[k];
            list[k] = temp;

            temp2 = index[k - 1];  //IN THE SAME MOMENT - DATA IS BEING SHUFFLED
            index[k - 1] = index[k];
            index[k] = temp2;
          } 
        i++;
    }

 return index;  //FUNCTION RETURNS VECTOR WITH SHUFFLED VALUES
```

`N` is same as `length` and is the length of `list`

I debugged this code in Visual Studio 2012 and I found that there is an issue in line:

```
for (int k = i; list[k - 1] > list[k]; k--){
```

The problem concerns Out Of Range error.

I can provide Call Stack if needed.

Can anyone help me with changing this `while` and `for` loop just to save the funcionality of `sort_index()` function?

Best regards,

JR

Comment: You didn't catch negative values of k.

Comment: Put `k &&` in front of that conditional test.

Answer (score 3):

On the second iteration of

```
for (int k = i; list[k - 1] > list[k]; k--){
```

k equals to 0 and `list[k - 1]` will call exception

Answer (score 2):

Surely it should be:

for (int k = i; (k > 0) && (list[k - 1] > list[k]); k--){

as otherwise there doesn't seem to be anything to stop k from dropping off the start of the array.